# How to save the language choice of user and change the overall app language in windows phone 8?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, localization, isolatedstorage

I am trying to localize my windows phone 8.0 app (SilverLight). I want to change the default `Appresources.resx` file upon user choice. When the user changes the language from the settings page I want to save it by in IsolatedStorageSettings and then indicate the saved language's `Appresources` file in `InitializeLanguage()` method which was called in my constructor of `app.xaml.cs` class.

I learned the theoretical process but I'm unable to go further on how to approach it.

Following are the code snippets for a better understanding of my problem.

```
private void InitializeLanguage()
        {
            try
            {
                RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage);
                FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection), AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
                RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And this the settings page code behind where I initially changed the language of a text box for test purposes which changes the language of the `TextBox` in runtime.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            ChangeLanguageCombo.Items.Add(new LanguageComboBox
            {
                Name = "English",
                Code = "en-US"
            });

            ChangeLanguageCombo.Items.Add(new LanguageComboBox
            {
                Name = "Bangla",
                Code = "bn"
            }); 
        }

    public static IsolatedStorageSettings ChangedLanguage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    
    private void ChangeLanguageCombo_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var languageComboBox = ChangeLanguageCombo.SelectedItem as LanguageComboBox;
        ApplyChange(new CultureInfo(languageComboBox.Code.ToString()));
        //now I want to save the user choice to the `IsolatedStorageSettings ChangedLanguage` and restart the app to take place the changes.
        MessageBox.Show("Restart");
        //after restart I want to indicate the Appresources file to the new selected one,(in InitializeLang() method) RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage); in this line
        }
            
    }

    private void ApplyChange(CultureInfo culInfo)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culInfo;
        textBlockHello.Text = AppResources.Salutation;
    }
```

I am sorry if the question is too clumsy to understand my purpose, I am new in this field and any kind of help or edit suggestion will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retrieving the value of LocalStorageSettings from App.xaml.cs class:

```
string value= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userData"] as string;
```

In `App.xaml.cs` I added following code under the try block of method `InitializeLanguage()`

```
private void InitializeLanguage()
{
    try
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("selectedLang"))
        {
             var changedLang = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["selectedLang"] as string;
             if (changedLang != null) ApplyChange(new CultureInfo(changedLang));
        }            
     }
     //rest of the part in this method remained same 
}
private void ApplyChange(CultureInfo culInfo)
{
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culInfo;
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culInfo;
}
```

And in my settings page when user selects a preferred language:

```
        public static IsolatedStorageSettings ChangedLanguage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        private void ChangeLanguageCombo_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var languageComboBox = ChangeLanguageCombo.SelectedItem as LanguageComboBox;

            if (languageComboBox != null)
            {
                if (!ChangedLanguage.Contains("selectedLang"))
                {
                    ChangedLanguage.Add("selectedLang", languageComboBox.Code.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    ChangedLanguage["selectedLang"] = languageComboBox.Code.ToString();
                }
                ChangedLanguage.Save();
                MessageBox.Show("Restart");
            }

        }
```

After restarting the app the default `Appresources` file would be the new languages's `Appresources` file as it was saved on the `IsolatedStorageSettings` and on app launching the `App.xaml.cs` page calls the `InitializeLanguage()` method.
So this is the way how I was able to change the default `Appresources` file when user changes the language of my app from the settings page.